# Azure stack hardware requirement - proposal

Tags: azure, azure-stack

I have received following following proposal from IT team, want to validate if this is good configuration to evaluate azure stack.

Features
HP IDS Z8 G4 WKS
Single Unit (Tower) Packaging
HP Z8 G4 90 1125W APJ Chassis 100V/15A
Windows 10 Pro 64 Workstations Plus INDIA
Operating System Load to SATA/SAS
Intel Xeon 6128 3.4 2666MHz 6C CPU
Intel Xeon 6128 3.4 2666MHz 6C 2nd CPU
96GB (12x8GB) DDR4 2666 DIMM ECC Registered 2CPU Memory APJ
NVIDIA Quadro P400 2GB (3)mDP GFX
500GB 7200RPM SATA 3.5in
500GB 7200RPM SATA 3.5in 2nd
500GB 7200RPM SATA 3.5in 3rd
USB Business Slim Wired Keyboard INDIA
HP Hardened Wired Mouse USB
No Included ODD
Base FIO 4xUSB3 TypeA
HP Remote Graphics Software (RGS) for Z
3/3/3 (material/labor/onsite) Warranty SING
No Adapters Needed
HP Z8 G4 1125W Country Kit INDIA
HP Z8 Std Cooling Solution 2CPU

Thanks.

Comment: azure stack cannot be installed on your existing hardware

Answer (score 0):

This won’t work. Requirements are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/asdk/asdk-deploy-considerations#hardware

Min requirement is one boot disk plus 4 additional disk